# Changing the "locale preferred encoding"

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-3.x, locale

[Using Python 3.2]

If I don't provide `encoding` argument to `open`, the file is opened using `locale.getpreferredencoding()`. So for example, on my Windows machine, any time I use `open('abc.txt')`, it would be decoded using `cp1252`.

I would like to switch all my input files to `utf-8`. Obviously, I can add `encoding = 'utf-8'` to all my `open` function calls. Or, better, `encoding = MY_PROJECT_DEFAULT_ENCODING`, where the constant is defined at the global level somewhere.

But I was wondering if there is a clean way to avoid editing all my `open` calls, by changing the "default" encoding. Is it something I can change by changing the locale? Or by changing a parameter inside the locale? I tried to follow the Python manual but failed to understand how this is supposed to be used.

Thanks!

Comment: Before I found this question, I've asked a differently worded duplicate and received some answers. You may find them useful: [Is there a way to change Python's open() default text encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24897644/3075942)

Comment: There're some more answers in the similar question: [Changing the “locale preferred encoding” in Python 3 in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469707/changing-the-locale-preferred-encoding-in-python-3-in-windows)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61570285/7796217 for a solution which I got working on Python 3.7.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61570285/7796217 for a solution I got working on Python 3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows, with Python 3.3+, execute `chcp 65001` in the console or a batch file before running Python in order to change the locale encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks. It does not work for Python 3.2 unless I `set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`, but it seems to work for Python 3.3. Let me try it some more, and I'll update this comment.

Comment: This accepted answer doesn't work for me at all. I tried both `chcp 65001` and `set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`. Please see my "answer" below, which should really be here in this comment location. Thanks.

Comment: Codepage 65001 is broken for use in the console. There are multiple bugs related to the console host process, conhost.exe, and C runtime. It's getting better with each version, but even Windows 10 with VC++ 14 isn't bug free yet. Also, this only affects `_Py_device_encoding` for stdin, stdout, and stderr. `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns the Windows ANSI encoding -- as it should.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for the info, but it has too much Windows-specific jargon for me. I rarely use Windows. All I want is a way to say to either Windows 8 or to Python 3: "Dear Windows 8 / Python 3, Please be informed that all the text files on this computer should be encoded in UTF-8 without exception. Please remember this fact in the future when opening text files. Thanks."

Comment: `chcp` is not necessary and does not solve the problem - it just controls your terminal's settings and has nothing to do with IO or opening files. PYTHONIOENCODING is a better way to go but this does not solve the problem in this case either - it just controls stdio (piping from/to stdin/stdout).