# Is there a way to change Python's open() default text encoding?

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, locale, default

Can I change default [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) <sup>([`io.open()` in 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/io.html#io.open))</sup> text encoding in a cross-platform way?

So that I didn't need to specify each time `open(...,encoding='utf-8')`.

> In text mode, if *encoding* is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to get the current locale encoding.

Though documentation doesn't specify how to *set* preferred encoding. The function is in `locale` module, so I need to change locale? Is there any reliable cross-platform way to set UTF-8 locale? Will it affect anything else other than the default text file encoding?

Or locale changes are dangerous (can break something), and I should stick to custom wrapper such as:

```
def uopen(*args, **kwargs):
    return open(*args, encoding='UTF-8', **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't change the locale or preferred encoding because;

- it may affect other parts of your code (or the libraries you're using); and
- it wont be clear that your code depends on `open` using a specific encoding.

Instead, use a simple wrapper:

```
from functools import partial
open_utf8 = partial(open, encoding='UTF-8')
```

You can also specify defaults for all keyword arguments (should you need to).

Comment: I've tried `locale.setlocale()` and it didn't change the default encoding on Windows. Even to a different non-Unicode one. So I decided to inspect CPython's source code and found out that `getpreferredencoding` [uses](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f7eae0adfcd4c50034281b2c69f461b43b68db84/Modules/_localemodule.c#L304) [GetACP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070(v=vs.85).aspx) WinAPI function, it "retrieves the current Windows ANSI code page identifier".

Comment: There is no mechanism in Python to override this behavior except to use version-dependent hacks like the one suggested by Joran in the other answer and those found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469707/changing-the-locale-preferred-encoding-in-python-3-in-windows). From what I've read, there is also no mechanism to set this encoding to UTF-8 in Windows outside of Python. Therefore, given the fact that there is no way to set this preference without resorting to hacks, I agree that changing this may be unreliable. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

you can set the encoding ... but its really hacky

```
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding() #should print your default encoding
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8") #error ... no setdefaultencoding ... but...
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")  #now it succeeds ...
```

I would instead do

**main_script.py**

```
import __builtin__
old_open = open
def uopen(*args, **kwargs):
    return open(*args, encoding='UTF-8', **kwargs)
__builtin__.open = uopen
```

then anywhere you call `open` it will use the utf8 encoding ... however it may give you errors if you explicitly add an encoding

or just explicitly pass the encoding any time you open a file , or use your wrapper ...

pythons general philosophy is explicit is better than implicit, which implies the "right" solution is to explicitly declare your encoding when opening a file ...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's safe to just overwrite the function in `builtins` as that also modifies the function in already imported modules and some libraries may rely on the default value. Still, it may come in handy in some cases. Thanks, +1

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to change the default encoding, you can replace the built-in `open` function.

```
original_open = __builtins__.open
def uopen(*args, **kwargs):
    if "b" not in (args[1] if len(args) >= 2 else kwargs.get("mode", "")):
        kwargs.setdefault("encoding", "UTF-8")
    return original_open(*args, **kwargs)
__builtins__.open = uopen
```

I wrote and tested this snipped after I found [this mails](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-April/724189.html) about replacing `print` on a mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **PEP 540** (UTF-8 Mode) is what you want:

https://peps.python.org/pep-0540/

#### Use `-Xutf8`

```
python.exe -Xutf8 -c "open('tmp.txt', 'w').write('天地玄黄0123'); print(open('tmp.txt').read())"
```

#### Use `PYTHONUTF8` in PowerShell

```
$env:PYTHONUTF8=1; python.exe -c "open('tmp.txt', 'w').write('天地玄黄0123'); print(open('tmp.txt').read())"
```

#### Use `PYTHONUTF8` in Cmd

```
set PYTHONUTF8=1&& python.exe -c "open('tmp.txt', 'w').write('天地玄黄0123'); print(open('tmp.txt').read())"
```

#### Use `PYTHONUTF8` in Bash

```bash
PYTHONUTF8=1 python -c "open('tmp.txt', 'w').write('天地玄黄0123'); print(open('tmp.txt').read())"
```

You can also execute `setx PYTHONUTF8 1` to save it as user-level environment variable.

Comment: The only answer that worked for me in python 3! Although for a proper test, I think you should exclude the `encoding='utf8'` parameter to make it fail. Otherwise, it works successfully without setting the environment variable.

Answer (score -1):

I would not change anything in `locale`, as it could have a lot of side effects in other parts of your system. `open` is a system level function call, so its settings can have effects outside of that, or at a minimum other Python programs that use the same Python installation. Your wrapper looks appropriate, is very clean and portable, and looks to be the correct solution.