# How to fix TypeError "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

With python 3.8 I am trying to get a list of `git` logs using `subprocess`, and then to process them. Here is a piece of the code:

```
lines = subprocess.check_output(
    [
        "git",
        "log",
        "--all",
        "--no-merges",
        "--shortstat",
        "--reverse",
        "--pretty=format:'%ad;%an'",
    ]
).splitlines()

for line in lines:
    print(line)
    if "file changed" in line or "files changed" in line:
        print("do something")
```

But I get an error:

```
....
if "file changed" in line or "files changed" in line:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

and the line print gives some output like

```
b"'Tue Nov 9 10:18:31 2010 +0000;someuser'"
```

That object looks like a byte object (see the 'b'?). Converting that object to a `str` and printing it, I get:

```
print(str(line))
b"'Tue Nov 9 10:18:31 2010 +0000;someuser'"
```

But I do not want to work with byte objects, I want to work with simple strings! So I am not sure what is going on. And why there are two quotes in that line.

How to convert the lines I get from the `splitlines` to normal strings I can compare with in `if` statements ad given in the code example?

Comment: try `if 'x' in str(line)` so your line is converted to a string

Comment: When I convert `line` to a `str`, I still get the 'b' in front when I `print(str(line))`. That seems very strange. I get the EXACT same output! Why do I still get that 'b'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615414/how-to-convert-binary-string-to-normal-string-in-python3

Comment: So `splitlines` returns a list of encoded objects, which I have to decode? Is that correct?

Comment: it's is a binary string then splitlines() will return a list of binary strings.  if it's not, it will return regular strings.  `subprocess.check_output()` is returning a binary string.

Comment: I had an older code where I "converted" the output from `subprocess.check_output()` to a string(?) using `str`. Now it does not seem to work anymore. My old code was something like: `lines = str(subprocess.check_output()).split()`. Why does `str` not wor with the example in my question?

Comment: Ok maybe In understand. I splitted the WHOLE thing, which contained only one 'b'. Now I have 'b's for every line. I also will NEVER understand this bytestring/string encoding stuff. I give up.

Comment: just do `subprocess.check_output(.....).decode().splitlines()` - The output from subprocess has quotes, so when you print the string you see double quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, maybe I understand

Comment: In the linked duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279764/python-unicodedecodeerror-how-to-correctly-read-unicode-strings-from-subproces, see in particularly the answer by tripleee, instead of the accepted one.

Comment: The "whole" thing didn't _contain_ any `b`. `b'123'` is one three-character bytestring; the only things it contains are `b'1'`, `b'2'`, and `b'3'`, each of which are single-character bytestrings; the `b`s in the front is how `repr()` shows that they are in fact bytestrings instead of unicode strings, not part of the content. Bytestrings are made of individual bytes, just like unicode strings are made up of (potentially-multibyte) characters.